# Unique result set with inner join query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM `catalog_webdesign_products` t 
INNER JOIN tbl_member_registration t1 ont.userid=t1.fld_loginid 
WHERE 1 
    AND t1.fld_member_category_level<9 
    AND t.product_img IS NOT NULL  
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

In this query , I need rows with unique userid. I had tried 'group by userid' also but then product_img with null value is coming in result set.

Comment: @goodmood From OP above "I had tried 'group by userid' also but then product_img with null value is coming in result set."

Comment: @goodmood - you could use `rollback` option instead of editing again. :)

Answer (score 2):

yes you can use `GROUP BY userid`. but your query looks wrong here

```
   INNER JOIN tbl_member_registration t1 on t.userid=t1.fld_loginid
                                           ^------------------------space here
```

try this

```
  SELECT 
  * 
  FROM `catalog_webdesign_products` t 
  INNER JOIN tbl_member_registration t1 on t.userid=t1.fld_loginid 
  WHERE  t1.fld_member_category_level<9 
  AND t.product_img IS NOT NULL  
  group by userid
  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

edit:

```
 SELECT 
  * 
  FROM (select * from `catalog_webdesign_products` where product_img IS NOT NULL) t 
  INNER JOIN tbl_member_registration t1 on t.userid=t1.fld_loginid 
  WHERE  t1.fld_member_category_level<9 
  group by t.userid
  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

Comment: when I use **GROUP BY userid**, it gives unique result but product_img with null values also come in result.

Answer (score 0):

For better performance you should move the condition for t1 into join statement. You problem could be the wrong JOIN condition. Try LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.

More about joins: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

```
SELECT * 
FROM `catalog_webdesign_products` t 
LEFT JOIN tbl_member_registration t1 
ON (t.userid = t1.fld_loginid AND t1.fld_member_category_level < 9)
WHERE t.product_img IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY t.userid 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```